# PHP Array from list data

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I know helping with homework generally isn't accepted around here, but I've been stuck for over a week now, so I would be more than grateful for any help. It seems simple in concept, but I can't get from exploding the file to getting that info into an array.

The goal is to have something to compare the text entered from a form to. For example, if the name Bob is typed into the name field then there would be a way to see if Bob's name was already on the list.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sname'],$_POST['snumber'],$_POST['courseselect']))
    {
        //Has to be submitted first
        $studentname = $_POST['sname'];
        $studentnumber = $_POST['snumber'];
        $course = $_POST['courseselect'];
        if(empty($studentname) || empty($studentnumber))
        {
            //make sure all fields are filled in
            echo "All fields must be filled in";//for if they aren't filled in
        }
        else 
        {
            //if they are filled in
            $studentfile = "students";
            $SF = fopen($studentfile, 'r') or die("$studentfile cannot be opened for reading");

            while($studentlist = fgets($SF))
            {
                list ($stoodname, $stoodnumber) = explode('::', $studentlist);
                $testarray[] = array('$stoodname');
                echo $testarray;
            }
        }
        //end of if/else
    }//end of "has to be submitted"
?>
```

I feel like I'm just missing something obvious :(

Comment: Just noticed you trying to echo an array - try print_r($testarray); instead of echo;

Comment: It gave me a huge list of "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => $stoodname )"

Comment: and to get file content in an array - try file() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: I can access the names by having echo "$stoodname <br>"; so I'm assuming my error is in the construction of the array?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it another try!

Comment: What is the format of the file? It is simple a CSV with `::` as the field separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your student file is a CSV with `::` between the fields:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sname'],$_POST['snumber'],$_POST['courseselect']))
    {
        //Has to be submitted first
        $studentname = $_POST['sname'];
        $studentnumber = $_POST['snumber'];
        $course = $_POST['courseselect'];
        if(empty($studentname) || empty($studentnumber))
        {
            //make sure all fields are filled in
            echo "All fields must be filled in";//for if they aren't filled in
        }
        else 
        {
            //if they are filled in
            $studentfile = "students";
            $SF = fopen($studentfile, 'r') or die("$studentfile cannot be opened for reading");

            while($studentlist = fgets($SF))
            {
                $testArray=explode('::', $studentlist);
                for($i=0;$<count($testArray);$i++)
                {
                    if($testArray[$i]==$studentname)
                    {
                        // You found your match!
                    }
                }
                print_r($testArray);
                unset($testArray);
            }
        }
        //end of if/else
    }//end of "has to be submitted"
?>
```

Comment: The student file is a CSV seperated by :: but has the student names as well as student numbers, this helps a bit though!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it can work.

What's wrong is the part:

```
$testarray[] = array('$stoodname');
```

When you put a variable in single quotes - it will be treated as a string.

Try

```
$testarray[] = $stoodname;

// other dirt

$studentExists = in_array($stoodname, $testarray);

if($studentExist) {
    //  code
}
```